# ionic local storage and checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have created a checkbox in a modal:
but when ever I close and reopen the modal, the items that were checked are not shown as checked. here are my codes

```
<div class="list">
 <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="thema in themen track by $index"
   type="checkbox"
   id="{{thema.id}}"
   ng-model="thema.checked"
   ng-checked="{{getCheck($index)}}">
   {{ thema.name }}
 </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

and in the js file I have added

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
 $scope.modal.show();
  $scope.themen = [
   { name: 'something', id: 1 },
   //some other objects
   ];
};
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.updateThemaLocalStorage = function ($index) {
       $window.localStorage.setItem( $index, $scope.themen[$index].checked );
   };
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
```

also in `gulp watch` I recive    `error  "$index" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 1):

The code about data retrieval from LocalStorage is missing, so assuming is similar to the following lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.themen.length; i++) {
    $scope.themen[i].checked = $window.localStorage.getItem(i);
}
```

This code does not work because the **checked** property is stored as string and so you need to convert to boolean:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.themen.length; i++) {
    $scope.themen[i].checked = toBool($window.localStorage.getItem(i));
}
```

...

```
function toBool(a) {
    if (a=="true") return true; else return false;
}
```